# Load json file in project to app.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

How do I load a json file in the project to the app.js. I tried

```
var j = require('./JSON1');
```

but it didnt work. I want later to use the JSON.stringify function in the app.js and send part of it to the client.
Anyone knows how to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: That should work. I'm doing the exact same thing. When you say "it didn't work", are you getting an error?

Answer (score 4):

`require` is for code, but JSON is pure data. You don't want JSON to be code, as non-javascript environments should be able to parse it.  As with any data file, you process it in two steps. First you read in the data, then you parse it.

[`fs.readFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) should let you read the file into a string. And then you can `JSON.parse(result)` that string to get JSON data.

```
fs.readFile('./JSON1', function(err, result) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  var data = JSON.parse(result);
  console.log(data); // parsed JSON data! yay!
});
```

Comment: `require` actually will happily load a JSON file for you. Not to say that I'd recommend it is general server usage, since it blocks, but for loading config for instance, it's not unreasonable.

Comment: I dont know why but it says that err is not defined in the throw err statement

Answer (score 0):

require is only when you have a module exposed in the included file.
What you want is plain file inclusion. For that there is a npm package called fs (filesystem)

Example code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var fileToOpen = "./JSON1"; 
fs.readFile(fileToOpen,function(error,data){
                if (error){
                    console.log("error opening file",error);
                }

                console.log("contents",data);
});
```